# What DITA element to use for a programming language's type name in synph?

Tags: dita

Given some programming language text, such as

```
int foo (int a);
```

or

```
function foo (a : int) return int;
```

and a goal of putting markup around the structurally significant parts, guided by syntax. What would be the proper choice of an element into which to put `int`, a *type*'s name, as part of a `<synph>`? Note that this markup is not meant for displaying blocks of code, but for delineating [syntactic structure](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/os/part2-tech-content/langRef/technicalContent/syntaxdiagram.html#syntaxdiagram)). I get as far as

```
int <var>foo</foo>
<delim>(</delim>
  int <parmname>a</parmname>
<delim>)</delim><delim>;</delim>
```

Even `<var>` doesn't seem right around the function's name, insofar as `var` means replaceable, but not all functions are. Just `<text>`?

I realize that the example uses names of individuals whereas railroad diagrams, grammars, etc. would have more abstract names. So, perhaps a more usual example is

```
function FUNCTION-NAME (VAR-NAME : TYPE-NAME) return TYPE-NAME;
```

Accordingly, the varied question becomes: What markup do I use for `TYPE-NAME`? Will a DITA specialization be practical?

Answer (score 0):

The correct element for a block of code is `codeblock`. You should not markup every single string. This only makes sense for inline elements. You may want to have a look at all related elements of the [programming domain](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/os/part3-all-inclusive/langRef/containers/pr-d.html#progd). If you publish your data, you should use a highlighter to automatically highlight the syntax of your block. You can use the `@outputclass` to tell the highlighter which language it has to use.

Comment: It's not about lines of code, or highlighting. The goal is to have meaningful markup of the (syntactic) structure of all parts involved, i.e., indicating the roles.

Comment: An [assessment](http://www.scriptorium.com/2013/01/perplexed-by-complex-syntax-understanding-syntax-diagrams-in-dita/) of the difference.